# how to run jest test from multiple locations in VSCode

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I managed to mock typeorm to an extent but then now I'm facing a strange issue that I'll illustrate here.

```
import { myEntity } from './entity';
import typeorm = require('typeorm');

describe('test suire'), () => {

  let myRepository: typeorm.Repository<myEntity>;

  test('my test case', () => {

    typeorm.Repository = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      createQueryBuilder: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        where: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        getMany: jest.fn().mockReturnValue([]);
      })
    });

    myRepository = new typeorm.Repository();

    expect(myRepository.createQueryBuilder).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);

  })
})
```

I have a package structure like this:

```
root/
    package.json
    project1/
            package.json
            src/
               the_above_test.spec.ts
```

When I run `node_modules/.bin/jest path_to_above_test.spec.ts` from `project1` it works. But when I run the same command from `root` I get:

```
Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has value: undefined at line:

    expect(myRepository.createQueryBuilder).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
```

The intention here is to debug the test from within VS Code. But since VS code is open at the root level, it executes the test from there. If there's no bug in my code, how can I tell VS Code to run the test from the `project1` directory?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Sorry I don't think I understand. This all started because I want to run Jest from Visual Code that is open at the root level. I wouldn't have this issue if I can tell Jest in VS Code to run from project1 but I couldn't figure this out.

Comment: this would work of course, but my intention is to be able to debug from within VS Code.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I fixed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify different jest configurations in your `/.vscode/launch.json`

Each configuration will have it's own working directory, specified using `"cwd"`.

here's a working example:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "name": "functions",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/packages/functions/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
            "args": [
                "./test/eventHooks.test.ts",
                "--runInBand"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/packages/functions",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"

        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "name": "functions",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/packages/types/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
            "args": [
                "./test/eventHooks.test.ts",
                "--runInBand"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/packages/types",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"

        }

    ]
}
```